# Pass table value to a form on button click

Tags: php, function, get

I am new here and also don't know PHP.

I have got a project in which there is a table containing a Buy button in one cell and its value in another cell.

I want it like that, when the user clicks on "BUY", it's value gets passed to a contact form.
Like for example: ?buyrate={value from table cell}

I have got the form working to receive the value from the URL.
Eg: ?buyrate=25 . The form field gets the value 25.

But i dont know how to get the value from the cell, so that the admin can be able to change the Value and doesn't need to change the Button URL every time.

Please help anyone.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show some code?

Comment: You can send values from one page to another with forms (using POST or GET), with $_SESSION variables/cookies. Maybe make the button part of a form and the action is contact-us.php, and POST all data you need, the ID, whatever else they chose, etc

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already getting buyrate from the URL (I assume from a $_GET ie `$buyrate = $_GET['buyrate'];`), why don't you simply use that value in your button code, like such:

```
<input type="submit" name="buyrate" value="<?php echo $buyrate; ?>" />
```

Without seeing code, we're not sure what else you want to submit, but this should pass that value to whatever your form action is.

Answer (score 0):

you need to send data via jquery to contact form like

```
//include jquery.js here

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#but').click(function(){
  var val=$('#v').html();
  window.location.href="somepage.php?buyrate="+val;
 });
});
</script>
<table>
<tr><td id="but"><button value="Buy" /></td></tr>
<tr><td id="v">60</td></tr>
</table>

//this is just an example you can modify the code as per your conditions and requirements.
```